# How do I count the amount of released units?

Tags: anylogic

I want to create a plot which visualize how often a unit was released. But unfortunately I have no idea how I can do this. Can anyone please help me? My process graph looks like this. I want to count how often depots were released [Process Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83OU9.png)

[Ressource Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ7uO.jpg)
[Agent + Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJJSK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

in the resourcepool object you can use the on release action to do that, just add a variable "timesReleased" in the resource agent and in that action you can just add `unit.timesReleased++;`

in the resourcepool object add the units created to a custom population (you will have to create the population of agents)

in that population you can use the statistics section to count the total number of times all the resources were released or anything you want.. .it's unclear what you need exactly so i won't be specific.

Comment: Hi Felipe Thank You very much for your help this my first time working with Anylogic, so excuse me for being a bit vague with my formulation of my question :) I want to count the amount an AGV drives to all Picking Station, in which a worker is fulfilling the order picking. I thought If I count how often the working Station was seized respectively released would work for this case.I hope this describes my problem more understandable.

Comment: Hello @Felipe, I tried to implement your suggestions.  I added on the resource pool the command "unit.timesReleased++;" On Release and add a Variable "timesReleased" in the agent workstation. Now I want to collect the count of how often the depot is released in a plot. Can you please show me how to do it? For  Clarification I added a screenshot of your modification in my original post. I wish you a nice day!

Comment: ask a new question

Comment: Alright I created a new question with more Information @Felipe